# Maximize variance in vector comparison

Tags: r

Lets say I have a set of numbers:

```
a <- 1:10
```

I want to create all non-redundant pairs from these numbers:

```
pairs <- t(combn(1:10,2))
```

Then for each pair I check whether the first element of the pair is larger than the second:

```
a[pairs[,1]]>a[pairs[,2]]
```

Since the dataset is sorted I get `FALSE` for each pair since the second element of the pair is always larger.

I can reshuffle the original dataset:

```
a<-sample(a)
```

and redo the same comparison:

```
 a[pairs[,1]]>a[pairs[,2]]
```

Now I get both TRUE and FALSE cases.

My question is: is there a way to maximize the variance: i.e, have equal or approximately equal number of TRUE and FALSE cases for any size variable `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question!

Here is an algorithm to give you the desired permutation of X=(1,2,3...,n):

Initially take empty result vector Y and set `round = 1`. For every round do:

1. Take first and last item from X
2. Append the pair of items to Y. If round-number is odd then append smaller one first. If round is even then append bigger one first.
3. Remove the selected items from X

Repeat until X is exhausted. If length of X is odd then in the end just add the final item to Y.

So in the end Y = (1,n,n-1,2,3,n-3,..., n/2).

---

Here is an R-implementation of the above algorithm:

This is non-random and it's guaranteed to return equal (or as equal as possible if the total number is not even) number of True and False cases for all lengths `n > 1`

```
max_var_sequence = function(n) {
  mid_point = ceiling((n+1)/2)

  #initiate the vector
  a1 = rep(mid_point,n)

  for(i in 1:(n/2)) {
    even = i %% 2
    a1[i*2 - even] = i
    a1[i*2 - !even] = n + 1 -i

  }
  return(a1)
}

n = 20
pairs <- t(combn(1:n,2))
s = max_var_sequence(n)
x = s[pairs[,1]]>s[pairs[,2]]

table(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work. In expectation you'd converge to equal number of TRUE and FALSEs.

```
pairs <- t(combn(1:10,2))

for (i in 1:nrow(pairs)) {
  if (runif(1) > .5) {
    tmp <- pairs[i,1]
    pairs[i,1] <- pairs[i,2]
    pairs[i,2] <- tmp
  }
}
table(pairs[,1] > pairs[,2])
# FALSE  TRUE
#    25    20
```